# Show that the plane $3x-2y-z=0$ cuts the cones $21x^2-4y^2-5z^2=0$ and $3yz-2zx+2xy=0$ in the same pair of perpendicular lines.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, solid-geometry

> Show that the plane $3x-2y-z=0$ cuts the cones $21x^2-4y^2-5z^2=0$ and $3yz-2zx+2xy=0$ in the same pair of perpendicular lines.

I am not understanding the problem. Don't what is the meaning of "same pair of perpendicular lines"? Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: The meaning is: the intersection between that plane and each cone is a pair of perpendicular lines, the same for both cones.

Comment: or: the two cones intersect along two parallel lines, and the plane is containing them.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $z=3x-2y$ into the equations of the two cones, you get in both cases:
$$
2x^2+2y^2-5xy=0,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
(2x-y)(x-2y)=0.
$$
The last equation is equivalent to $2x-y=0$ or $x-2y=0$, which are the equations of two planes.
Combining these with $z=3x-2y$ we then obtain two lines, whose direction vectors are $(1,2,-1)$ and $(2,1,4)$.

Comment: Ok. But what does it mean?

Comment: See my edited answer.